Completeness of $Y$ given a continuous bijective function from a complete metric Space $X$.
Given that $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $X$ is complete, there exists a bijective function $f: X \to Y$ that is continuous and the inverse function $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ is uniformly continuous. I want to prove that $Y$ is complete.
Proof:
Let $\{y_n \}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. If $\{y_n \}$ converges in $Y$, then $Y$ is complete.
Since $f$ is bijective, for each element $y_n \in Y$, there exists a unique element $x_n \in X$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$.
Since $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous it sends convergent sequences from $Y$ to convergent sequences in $X$. So if $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.
Since $X$ is complete the Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to some $x \in X$. Because $f$ is continuous it follows that $f(\{x_n\})$ converges to $f(x) \in Y$. Since $\{y_n\} = f(\{x_n\})$ this implies that $\{y_n\}$ converges to $f(x) \in Y$. So every Cauchy sequence in $\{y_n\}$ converge in $Y$ and therefore $Y$ is complete.
Does this suffice as a proof?

It is fine. The sentence ' If ${y_n }$ converges in $Y$, then $Y$ is complete' doesn't fit in. Just delete it.

"Since $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous it sends convergent sequences from $Y$ to convergent sequences in $X$. So if ${y_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence then ${x_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$."... This part is not clear to me. Could you elaborate? (Maybe I am missing something simple.)

Let ${ y_n }$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Given that $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y_i, y_j \in Y$, $d_Y(y_i, y_j) < \delta \implies d_X(f^{-1}(y_i), f^{-1}(y_j)) < \epsilon$.
Since ${ y_n }$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $i, j \geq N$, $d_Y(y_i, y_j) < \delta$. Hence, $d_X(f^{-1}(y_i), f^{-1}(y_j)) < \epsilon$ for all $i, j \geq N$, demonstrating that ${ f^{-1}(y_n) }$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.

@Mathstudent123 Thanks. To be clear then, I would say "Since $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous, it sends Cauchy sequences in $Y$ to Cauchy sequences in $X$..." Otherwise everything looks good.

@K.Jiang You are right! I appreciate your feedback! Thank you!

Thank you for your feedback @geetha290krm. I understand your point and will delete the sentence as it doesn't fit in the context.
